# How to get initialised SELF from a static init method

Tags: ios, objective-c

In the below code, I am try to have an init method that can be called statically, because believe that the initialisation method should be responsibility of the class.

However, in the below code .h , .m and main files, when compiled, the app crashes and the following message received:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[Synchron<0x1064540b0> init]: cannot init a class     object.'
```

Please let me know how to solve this error and why I am getting it.

**main**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Synchron.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

    [Synchron initSelfWithName:@"XYZ" andId:@"000"];
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

**.m**:

```
@implementation Synchron
@synthesize SynchronName;   
@synthesize SynchronId;

+(id)initSelfWithName:(NSString *)synchName andId:(NSString *)synchId {
    Synchron *synch;
    if (self == [super init]) {
    synch = [[Synchron alloc] init];
    synch.SynchronName = synchName;
    synch.SynchronId = synchId;
    NSLog(@"synch: %@", synch.SynchronName);
    NSLog(@"synch: %@", synch.SynchronId);
    }
    return synch;
}
@end
```

**.h**

```
@interface Synchron : NSObject {

}

@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *SynchronName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *SynchronId;

+(id) initSelfWithName: (NSString *) synchName andId: (NSString *) synchId;

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `self` in a class method. So `self` refers to a `class`, **not** an `object`. A `class` can not be initialize like `[super init]`.

When you call `[[Synchron alloc] init]`, it has two parts!

1. `[Synchron alloc]` returns an allocated **object**
2. `[allocatedObject init]` returns initialized **object**

So calling `[Synchron init]` is nonsense.

**Initialization** is not responsibility of the class! Only **allocation** is!

So:

```
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)synchName andId:(NSString *)synchId {
    self = [super init]; // Here `self` refers to an object, not the class. Because we are inside an instance method.
    if(self) {
        self.SynchronName = synchName;
        self.SynchronId = synchId;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then you can also have a instance builder class method like:

```
+ (instancetype)synchronWithName:(NSString *)synchName andId:(NSString *)synchId {
    return [[self alloc] initWithName: synchName andId: synchId];
}
```

Comment: would you please let me know how to correct it so to have a static initializer

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rob, It's been a while that I don't code in Objective-C. I forgot some of the conventions and resolution.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your code.

1. The use of `@synthesize` for standard properties is long obsolete.
2. You need your properties to be `strong`, not `weak`.
3. A class initializer should not start with `init`.
4. `self` in a class method represents the class, not an instance of the class.
5. Property names should start with lowercase letters.

Your updated code would be:

.h

```
@interface Synchron : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (string, nonatomic) NSString *id;

+ (instancetype)synchronWithName:(NSString *)name andId:(NSString *)id;

@end
```

.m

```
@implementation Synchron

+ (instancetype)synchronWithName:(NSString *)name andId:(NSString *)id {
    Synchron *synch = [[self alloc] init];
    synch.name = name;
    synch.id = id;

    return synch;
}

@end
```

Now you can use it as:

```
Synchron *val = [Synchron synchronWithName:@"XYZ" andId:@"000"];
```

Answer (score 0):

> In the below code, I am try to have an init method that can be called statically, because believe that the initialisation method should be responsibility of the class.

There is a defined "family" of methods for class initialization methods, just as instance initialization methods start with `init` class ones start with `new`. There is a default implementation of `new` and its [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1571948-new?language=objc) states:

> This method is a combination of `alloc` and `init`. Like `alloc`, it initializes the isa instance variable of the new object so it points to the class data structure. It then invokes the `init` method to complete the initialization process.

To define your method you follow the same pattern as you typically follow for defining a custom `init` method: you call it `new...` and invoke `new` to create the object you are specialising:

```
+(instancetype) newWithName:(NSString *)synchName andId:(NSString *)synchId
{
   Synchron *synch;

   synch = [self new];  // any call to new or alloc/init may return nil
   if (synch)               // so check before setting the properties
   {
      synch.synchronName = synchName;
      synch.synchronId = synchId;
   }
   return synch;
}
```

> Notes: the above has changed three things compared to your code
>
> 1. The property names start with a lowercase letter to follow the standard naming convention.
> 2. The return type has been changed to `instancetype`. This new keyword was added to Objective-C to improve type safety. It is used when a method returns an instance of its class, e.g. initialization and factory methods, and allows for better compiler warnings. For details of its exact meaning see the [instancetype](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ModernizationObjC/AdoptingModernObjective-C/AdoptingModernObjective-C.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014150-CH1-SW2) section in *Adopting Modern Objective-C*. You will still see `id` used a lot.
> 3. `self` is used rather than `Synchron` in the `new` call. In a class method `self` refers to the class (and not the instance as in an instance method) the method was called on. This change supports the case where the method has been called from a subclass of `Synchron` and therefore `self` refers to that subclass.
>
> *Credit: Changes 2 & 3 were originally omitted to simplify the answer but comments by @Rob on multiple answers encouraged us to include them for completeness. (Your code "works" without these changes.)*

This method has exactly the same return semantics as `alloc`/`init` and the returned value is owned by the caller and its lifetime will be managed by ARC (automatic reference counting). For more detail on method families see the section [Method Families](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#method-families) in the ARC documentation.

**Pre-ARC Era**

In the pre-ARC era, when you had to manually manage object lifetime – known as MRR (manual retain release) or MRC (manual reference counting), the `new` family of methods was less used. Instead factory methods following the naming convention `<classname>...`, in your case the method would have been:

```
+(id) synchronWithName:(NSString *)synchName andId:(NSString *)synchId
```

Such a method is not in the `new` or `init` families and therefore returns an unowned reference to the caller and ARC has to handle it slightly differently. **Important:** as its name implies ARC, *Automatic* Reference Counting, will handle such a factory method without the need for you to be concerned over the different semantics of the return value, however the code produced will be *very slightly* less efficient.

The body of the factory method can be exactly the same as the `new` family one, though it would be more common to use `alloc`/`init` to create the object:

```
+(instancetype) synchronWithName:(NSString *)synchName andId:(NSString *)synchId
{
   Synchron *synch;

   synch = [[self alloc] init];
   if (synch)
   {
      synch.synchronName = synchName;
      synch.synchronId = synchId;
   }
   return synch;
}
```

**Pick Your Style**

You will see a lot of the `<classname>...` factory methods around and probably quite a few less of the `new...` class initialisation methods. ARC handles both automatically and the efficiency difference will more than likely be insignificant to your code (*never* prematurely optimise, i.e. don't spend time on it unless you have an issue – but at the same time don't write intentionally poorly performant code!).

*Whether you go with the factory style or the `new` family style is your choice, there is no right or wrong one.*

HTH

Answer (score 0):

A couple of observations:

- The convention is to declare an `init` instance method that is used in conjunction with `alloc`, e.g.

  ```
  Synchron *synchron = [[Synchron alloc] initWithName:name identifier:identifier];
  ```
- If you want, you can also define a convenience class method to create an instance, though you generally wouldn’t use `init` prefix for that method name. Generally you’d use a prefix of the class name, e.g. `synchron`:

  ```
  Synchron *synchron = [Synchron synchronWithName:name identifier:identifier];
  ```

  You’d also define that method to return an `instancetype` rather than `id`, so the type checking system will automatically know what type it returns (and by using `instancetype` rather than explicitly using `Synchron *`, it works for subclasses, too).

  As CRD pointed out, you can also use the `new` prefix, so instead of `synchronWithName:identifier:`, it could be `newWithName:identifier:`. This is less common, but results in slightly different ARC behaviors in some edge cases, but isn’t material here.
- Minor observations, but we often define these properties such that:

  - property names begin with lowercase letter;
  - we use `copy` semantics to avoid problems of passing `NSMutableString` and having it mutate behind our backs; and
  - note that in the `synchronWithName` implementation, I use `[[self alloc] init]` syntax rather than `[[Synchron alloc] init]`, which ensures proper behavior should we ever subclass `Synchron`.

Thus, pulling this altogether:

```
@interface Synchron: NSObject

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *identifier;

- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name identifier:(NSString *)identifier;
+ (instancetype)synchronWithName:(NSString *)name identifier:(NSString *)identifier;

@end

@implementation Synchron

- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name identifier:(NSString *)identifier {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.name = name;
        self.identifier = identifier;
    }
    return self;
}

+ (instancetype)synchronWithName:(NSString *)name identifier:(NSString *)identifier {
    return [[self alloc] initWithName:name identifier:identifier];
}

@end
```

---

You say:

> I am try to have an `init` method that can be called statically, because believe that the initialisation method should be responsibility of the class.

Fundamentally, the allocation is the responsibility of the class, but the initialization is the responsibility of the instance. But, as shown above, it’s perfectly acceptable to offer the developer a convenience class method that does both the appropriate `alloc` and `init`.

Comment: The `new` pattern does not produce different behaviour just in ARC, its semantics has always followed that of the `alloc`/`init` combination, see [Basic Memory Management Rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1) from the MRC days.

Comment: Would the factory method pattern (`+<classname>...`) which returns an *autoreleased* object have dominated the use of the `new` family if Objective-C had started with automatic memory management? For someone starting Objective-C in the post-ARC era they will not hear "autoreleased* for a long time, in pre-ARC it was Obj-C 101 *because* of the need to manually manage memory. Why recommend a pattern devised to ease MRC/MMR when the language has always supported the `new` class initialiser family which is a better fit for ARC? (Yes, your deleted comment and this one are largely opinion based ;-))

Comment: @CRD - Re memory management, `newWithName:identifier:` and `synchronWithName:identifier:` can have different memory management behavior if not all targets are compiled with ARC (the former is +1, the latter is autorelease). It’s an edge case nowadays with the advent of ARC fast autorelease, so I’ll remove that noise from my answer.

Comment: @CRD - “Why recommend a pattern devised to ease MRC/MMR ...” - I deleted that comment to avoid debate, but if you insist (lol): 1. If anything, the `newXXX` convention (going back to that pre-ARC doc you quote) is the MRC anachronism, not `synchronWithXXX` pattern. Back in the day, we needed some naming convention to indicate the semantics of the returned object, a practice rendered largely obsolete by ARC enhancements. 2. The `synchronWithXXX` is the established, accepted convention and there is zero benefit in resurrecting a different (and outdated) `new` prefix convention.

Comment: Rob, I think between us we've suitably advertised that there is a difference of *opinion* here, job done.